# Martingale property for stochastic time changed Martingale processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

I came across a Lemma and proof in Tankov & Cont, financial modelling with jumps. The lemma and proof can be seen here:

[image]

I have a hard time understanding the reason for the relation in the following  part of the proof. Is it even correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That follows from optional stopping (as in the second sentence of the proof) because $(v_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is independent of $(M_t)_{t\ge 0}$.

On the other hand, the claim
$$
E\{E[M(v_t)|\mathcal F_s\vee\mathcal F^v_t]|\mathcal F_s\}=
E\{E[M(v_t)|\mathcal F^M_{v_s}\vee\mathcal F^v_t]|\mathcal F_s\}
$$
is less obvious because $\mathcal F_s\vee\mathcal F_t^v \subset \mathcal F^M_{v_s}\vee \mathcal F_t^v$ and the inclusion may be strict; still it is true by the Tower Property, because $\mathcal F_s\subset \mathcal F_s\vee\mathcal F^v_t$.

Comment: I thought that we have $\mathcal F_s\vee\mathcal F^v_t= \sigma(M(v_\tau), 0\le \tau\le s)\vee\sigma(v_\tau,0\le \tau\le s)\vee\sigma(v_\tau,0\le \tau\le t) = \sigma(M(v_\tau), 0\le \tau\le s)\vee\sigma(v_\tau,0\le \tau\le t)$. Because of this and the fact that the outer expectation is conditioned wrt $\mathcal F_s$, "we know" $v_s$, and therefore we have that $\sigma(M(v_\tau), 0\le \tau\le s)\vee\sigma(v_\tau,0\le \tau\le t)=\sigma(M(s), 0\le s\le v_\tau)\vee\sigma(v_\tau,0\le \tau\le t)$ simply because "we know" $v_s$?

Comment: I was trying to get at this: because $s\mapsto v_s$ may have jumps (or is this ruled out by the precise definition of "time change process" used by Tankov & Cont?), there is less information in $\mathcal F_s$ than in $\mathcal F^M_{v_s}$, for if $v_{u-}<v_u$ for some $u\in(0,s)$ then the piece of $M$, $(M_r: v_{s-}<r<v_s)$ is lost when passing to the time change.

Comment: Well, they seem not to have defined the time change process explicitly, but in the introduction to the section they have given some examples of time change processes as time integrals of stochastic variance models (CIR and OU processes). The processes achieved by time integrating are pathwise continuous.
If one assumes the time change processes does not have jumps, would the two filtrations be "equal"?
Note that $\mathcal F_s$ is not the natural filtration (they defined this filtration in the proof). How do you compare the information to be less than the other filtration in your example?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around, more information in $\mathcal F_s$ than in $\mathcal F_{v_s}^M$? Reasoning: $\mathcal F_{v_s}^M$ does not contain the jump information of the time change process over the path up to $v_s$, only the information of $v_s$, that is the time change process at time $s$? As you probably can guess, i'm rather new to this field.

Comment: If you elaborate how the optional stopping theorem was used to show this (using the filtration $\mathcal F^M_s\vee\mathcal F^v_\infty$, because $v_s$ and $v_s$ are $\mathcal F^M_s\vee\mathcal F^v_\infty$ stopping times with $v_s\le v_t$ and also use the fact that $M$ will be a martingale with respect to $\mathcal F^M_s\vee\mathcal F^v_\infty$ and further assume that $v_t$ is a bounded process) I could accept your answer.

Comment: @noidea I always wondered about this so I am glad someone is bothered about it. As John argues, the whether the inner conditioning occurs with respect to $\mathcal F_s$ or $\mathcal F^M_{v_s}$ (which may not coincide if $M$ is not constant on $[v_{t-},v_t]$) does not really bother me. What does worry me is the use of Doob's optimal stopping (sampling?) theorem without further assumptions on $v_t$ (e.g. boundedness). If you sorted it out, I'd be happy to hear